# Firebase phonenumber sign in after registration

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-signin, phone-number

I am working on a project made in Android Studio with Java and I am having some problem finding out, how I could store the sign in credential for later use, even if the application is restarted.

Storing some values for later use can be achieved with SharedPrefferences but unfortunately, it doesn't have the possibility to put an object only string, boolean, integer, float, long and stringset.

The credential variable comes from  the function

```
public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) 
{ 
  mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential) // where mAuth is FirebaseAuth
}
```

This process is done when the user first registers with his phone number and gets the verification code.
In some way or another, I found a workaround for this situation where I want the user to be signed in on some activities, but this, requires email and password and I would like just to maintain only the phone number, not requiring another type of registration using email and password.

The code for signing in with email and password works fine

```
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            your_email, your_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>(){
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "firebase auth success");
                requestLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "firebase auth failed");
                Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: Failed=" + task.getException().getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Investigate serialization - see if you can serialize the PhoneAuthCredential and then you'll be able to store it as a JSON string.

The Java library you'd use is Google's gson library: [A Java serialization/deserialization library to convert Java Objects into JSON and back](https://github.com/google/gson)

Note: not all objects can be easily serialized using gson, you might need to create a custom gson serializer in some cases.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the fast response, I will look into it and try this method.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to store the object in SharedPrefferences but from my point of view, this is the best approach.

You convert the object data in JSON format after that you can store the JSON data as a string in  SharedPrefferences.
Example:

```
String tripPlan = new Gson().toJson(childData);
```

Note:`childData` is a class object.